Adverb of Place vs. Predicate nominative
We were analyzing a sentence in class today, and an interesting issue came up. How do we differentiate between being verb + adverb of place and linking verb + predicate nominative?
The sentence was "This was two miles from the point of invasion." (From a short story we're reading). The antecedent for "this" is the noun "weir." I showed the kids how we could analyze it as a (subject-demonstrative pronoun) (linking verb) (predicate nominative+adjective prepositional phrase). However, I've been playing with it more, and I think there are a couple reasons why that's not the best analysis. 1) Two miles does NOT have the exact same semantic content as "this" or "weir." It's clearly a location of the thing, not the thing. That doesn't fit the definition of a predicate nominative. 2) I can substitute the verbs "lay" or "located" for "was," which seems to suggest a verb-adverb relationship, rather than a subject-linking verb-complement relationship.
Thoughts?

The structure of your sentence is like "This is red", not "This is a gun". We can use "to be" verbs for both identity and description.

It is LIKE that. I'm curious, though, about whether it IS that. For instance, I can say, "The test is next Monday," but "next Monday" and "the test" do not have a subject-complement relationship.

In English, noun phrases can function as locative or sometimes temporal adverbial adjuncts without needing to be the object or complement of their verb. We have many questions about this confusion. That's why they can appear with intransitive verbs: they're prepositionless adjuncts not objects. Part of the problem is that learners' materials and simplistic grammars misrepresent these because they don't want to teach grammar only parts of speech.  That leads to paradox and silliness.

Your second thought is right on.

This was two miles from the point of invasion.

Here, was is not a linking verb or copula, which has two uses: ascriptive and specifying. And we can see right off the bat that the latter use doesn't fit here. You can't say two miles from the point of invasion specifies what this was.
So now the only way was could be a copula is for two miles from the point of invasion to ascribe the property of this. But we can't substitute seemed or became for was here:

*This seemed two miles from the point of invasion. 
*This became two miles from the point of invasion.

Which means that it's not the ascriptive use either. Thus, it's not a copula. And your second analysis is correct. Also, two miles from the point of invasion is not a noun phrase (NP) but a preposition phrase (PP). The NP two miles is a complement of the PP from the point of invasion, just as the NP two hours is of the PP before the invasion in This was two hours before the invasion.

The point is that in your sentence you are not dealing with the copula. This is not a context of linking. Instead, "be" is the full verb which is defined as follows.

(SOED) be I As full vb. 3 (With advs. and prep. phrs.) Have or occupy a given position, exists in a stated circumstance, condition, or relation; occupy oneself in a given way, hold a given opinion, etc. OE (user LPH - OE: from Old English)
DYLAN THOMAS The house is 5 minutes from the station


The weir  occupies a place (that is) two miles from the point of invasion.


Some analysts posit that link verbs (especially be in said role) may take a PP complement.

@EdwinAshworth As in "She was before her time."?

[Linking Verbs] ... Examples: Other types of subject complement:
• The party was yesterday.
• The book is on the shelf. [Scribbr.co.uk]

@EdwinAshworth I think they are in error. "…was yesterday": the full verb. "…is on the shelf": no linking here either.

I think it's safe to say that "to be" may be one of the most complicated verbs in the language. It's not just a language issue, but philosophers run into many conundrums try to explain all the possible relationships that may be described as "X is Y".

So it may not be a good idea to open up this can of worms in a high school English class.

@Barmar What you say is true but in the present case it is not too difficult, a matter of distinguishing between main verb and linking verb (which some classify among main verbs, I will add, to rhyme with yo remarks). It is an exercice the student should try every time there is an opportunity.

I really appreciate the help, especially with the technical terminology used for different constituents. I want the students to learn to think critically about how the language works "in the wild," so I might open this can of worms. I think they'll be all right.
